As an intermediate R programmer looking to dive into machine learning, should I choose Python or stick with R?
Background
I am an intermediate R programmer with some experience in machine learning concepts and simple modeling in R. I have an opportunity to collaborate with a professional machine learning team that is okay with me using R, but I believe I will eventually need to switch to Python.
I use programming and ML mostly for research purposes (medicine) and publication. However, there is a tiny possibility of switching to a more product-based workflow.
My dilemma
I have two tasks:

Learn Python (which can be postponed if I continue with R, but I know I will eventually need to switch).
Master a machine learning tool (Tidymodels, mlr3, or scikit-learn) to impress the team during the interview.

As I said, task 1 can be done later. But, task 2 should be done in a few weeks. Therefore, if you think that I should go for Python, please consider that I have an interview in very near future, so I have to master both Python and ML.
I understand that Python is more memory-efficient and has better GPU access, but I’ve also heard good things about R’s ML packages like Tidymodels and mlr3.
Given that R has a promising future in ML but Python is currently more widely used, what should I do? What is the roadmap? If I should stick with R, which packages should I use and what resources should I learn?
Do you think that it is possible to get a hold of Python and Python's ML ecosystem in a couple of weeks?
ps. Someone asked me why I NEED to switch to Python. Based on consultations with experts, they mentioned that R is still quite immature and lacks memory and GPU efficiency, among other issues. But, I am not sure about that. I just want to learn the best tool possible, as soon as possible.

R statistics package is a large ecosystem of tools, purpose built and actively maintained for statistics by statisticians, for accomplishing a variety of statistics, machine learning and many other tasks in other fields of scientific computing. Most of the new developments in probability and statistics get quickly implemented in an R package. So you'll do well to continue to develop your knowledge and skills in R.
An ML researcher can implement their innovative method in Python and reach a wider audience than writing it in any other programming language or platform. This perpetrates a vicious cycle - due to the larger population of users and researchers using Python any new development in machine learning tends to be targeting Python users so that it is more widely available.
Hence, in today's environment almost all of deep learning tools and new developments in this field use Python libraries that become difficult (but not impossible) to integrate or interoperate with other languages. Hence, it is preferable to be familiar with those Python packages so you'll be able to work with other teams as well as better understand, enhance, or extend existing work.
You should follow both paths and continue with developing your R skills as well as learn and develop knowledge of Python libraries for machine learning.
